# Regex to strip all punctuation except '

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to strip all punctuation from a block of text that I import except for ', such as the ' in doesn't.

I currently have

> $words = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', '', $words);

Which strips all the punctuation, but I'm unsure of how to include '.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `preg_replace("/[^a-z']+/i", '', $words)`?

Comment: @DCoder, well, that was embarrassingly easy. If you could please post the question below I'll give you the tick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try it so

```
preg_replace( '/[^\w\']+|\'(?!\w)|(?<!\w)\'/', '', $words )
```

this should replace all non-letters and also single apostrophs outside a word

untested yet, please let me know if it works

*update*

to remove numbers, too, just use this regex

```
/[^\w\']+|\'(?!\w)|(?<!\w)\'|\d+/
```

just added `\d+`, so numbers matches and will be removed

Comment: I hadn't thought about non letters besides punctuation marks. This is actually important and something else I'll need. This strips everything but numbers are left over. Works very nicely for things such as 'foo' though, and that's another huge bonus. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To remove punctuation characters with unicode property, do:

```
 preg_replace('/\p{Punctuation}+/u', '', $words);
```

or

```
 preg_replace('/\p{P}+/u', '', $words);
```

To remove all punctuation except single quote:

```
 preg_replace("/[^\P{P}']+/u", '', $words);
```

Have a look at [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?!')\p{P}
```

to match any punctuation except an apostrophe. E.g.

```
preg_replace('/(?!\')\p{P}/gu', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?!'\b)[[:punct:]] ?/
```

This matches any punctuation character unless it's an apostrophe followed by a character (i.e. a word boundary, which implies a character).

See http://rubular.com/r/VJ0J5c25vc